# The required column was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy haciendo una web en *Asp.net mvc* donde tengo un modelo con los datos de un procedimiento almacenado traído desde *SqlServer 2014*

```
 public class spMostrarProductos
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdProducto { get; set; } 
        public string NombreProd { get; set; }
        public string ReferProd { get; set; }
        public string DescripProd { get; set; }
        public int StockProd { get; set; }
        public decimal CostoProd { get; set; }
        public decimal IvaProd { get; set; }
        public decimal Precio1Prod { get; set; }
        public decimal Precio2Prod { get; set; }
        public decimal Precio3Prod { get; set; }
    }
```

En el controlador lo traigo asi

```
 public List<spMostrarProductos> spProductos()
 {
    var productos = _context.MostrarProductos.FromSqlRaw("exec sp_MostrarProductos").ToList();
    return productos;
 }
```

Y en la vista lo traigo desde jquery para mostrarlo en una tabla dentro de un modal

```
 $(document).on('click', '.img-search', e => {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'Ventas/spProductos',
      success: data => {
      var table = $('#modalProduc').find('.table tbody');
      for (var i in data) {
          table.append('<tr><td>' + data[i].nombreProd + '</td><td>' + data[i].referProd + '</td></tr>');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Pero me sale este error en consola

> System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'CostoProd' was
> not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.

Y no entiendo el por que del error, si la columna esta tanto ahí como en el procedimiento almacenado, pero si quito todas las columnas de decimal, me trae los datos sin ningún problema.

¿Alguna solución?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asegúrate de que lo que te devuelve el procedimiento almacenado `sp_MostrarProductos`te devuelva la misma cantidad y mismos campos que declaras en `public class spMostrarProductos`, o sea que te devuelva todos estos campos:

```
public int IdProducto { get; set; } 
public string NombreProd { get; set; }
public string ReferProd { get; set; }
public string DescripProd { get; set; }
public int StockProd { get; set; }
public decimal CostoProd { get; set; }
public decimal IvaProd { get; set; }
public decimal Precio1Prod { get; set; }
public decimal Precio2Prod { get; set; }
public decimal Precio3Prod { get; set; }
```

Comment: Seguramente te sale porque en uno de los dos modelos, tanto el de c# como el de la base de datos, uno de los campos esta con un tipo de dato diferente. Revisa el tipo de dato que tiene el modelo de la DB y el tipo de dato del modelo de c#, ambos tienen que coincidir.